# How to mirror a NxNx3 numpy array diagonally

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I transpose a 3D array in a similar fashion to a 2D array, except that the entries at the lowest level are arrays of three instead of scalar values?

This is what I mean:

```
M = [[[0,0,0][1,1,1][2,2,2]]
     [[0,0,0][0,0,0][3,3,3]]
     [[0,0,0][0,0,0][0,0,0]]]

N = some_operation(M)

N = [[[0,0,0][0,0,0][0,0,0]]
     [[1,1,1][0,0,0][0,0,0]]
     [[2,2,2][3,3,3][0,0,0]]]
```

I have an example in python code that shows what I mean as well:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[3,3,3]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]])
N = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[0,0,0]]])

print(M)
print('\n\n')
print(M_flipped)
```

The `np.transpose()` function doesn't seem to be adaptable for my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply permute axes with [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
N = M.transpose(1,0,2)
```

Or with [`np.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) -

```
N = np.moveaxis(M,0,1)
```

With `np.rollaxis` -

```
N = np.rollaxis(M,1,0)
```